# Сравнение объектов класса

Tags: java, swing

подскажите имеется объект определенного класса содержащий `Map<String,DefaultTableModel>` подскажите каким образом можно сравнить два таких объекта, кроме как путем построчного сравнения DefaulTableModel, необходимо грубо говоря узнать изменялся ли объект или нет.

Comment: Что именно вы хотите сравнить: структуру модели или  все записи в моделях или конкретную запись. И если не секрет зачем вам целый Map с моделями таблиц? Напишите более подробно что вы хотите реализовать и приложите код который связан с вопром.

Comment: Надо сравнить записи в моделях.

Comment: Код очень большой, грубо говоря необходимо проверить изменились ли таблицы после загрузки из файла.

Comment: Ну если таблицы большие и вы не хотите сравнивать их целиком, может имеет смысл отслеживать изменения данных на ходу? Кто и как может менять данные?

Comment: Я понимаю, что просто могу проверить таблицы, я не понимаю почему при сравнении объектов всегда false.

Comment: Потому что в DefaultTableModel довольно большая структура, там далеко не только данные хранятся. Если вам надо сравнить данные, напишите метод который будет делать обход всех полей и сравнивать значения с исходными.